# Create user-managable card view

Tags: android

I wish to create kind of a responsive card view in Android, similar to this design found online:

[image]

I looked at number of tutorials, but all of them are creating a fixed number of rows/columns cards, which are great, but:

I need way more customisation:

- make it responsive (when rotating the phone): 2 columns looks nice in portrait, but crap on landscape
- I wish allowing my user to rearrange the cards
- later I wish to allow my user defining the layout (adding, resizing, removing cards)
- I also wish my user be able to customize the cards (background, image, backcolor, select Celsius instead Fahrenheit, etc)

I know these can all easily manageable by producing a **lot** of code, which I would avoid.

I'm pretty sure there are solutions for this in libraries, just I couldn't find any.

I wish to emphasize I don't necessarily want to avoid coding, but I don't want to re-code Android's widget system from scratch.

Comment: i'm not sure you'll find an answer here. `I'm pretty sure there are solutions for this in libraries, just I couldn't find any.` asking for library suggestions here is off-topic, unfortunately. beyond that, your list of requirements is quite extensive, i'm not sure if there's any real short/simple way of achieving this. might be simpler to just start by breaking this down line by line instead